# "this" in a method call in TypeScript?

Tags: closures, typescript

How do I want to make this work:

```
class TestClass {

   doMethod1 (arg1, arg2, cb)
   {
      this.doMethod2(arg1, arg2, function (result){cb (result)});
   }

  doMethod2 (arg1, arg2, cb) {
      this.doMethod3(arg1, arg2, function(result){cb (result)});
   }

  doMethod3 (arg1, arg2, cb) {
      var result = arg1 + arg2;
      cb(result);
   }
}
```

test = new TestClass;

test.doMethod3(1,1, cb); 
test.doMethod2(1,1,cb);

Both work.

test.doMethod1(1,1,cb);

EDIT: Actually, it does work.

I got around related lexical scoping issues by using the "fat arrow" syntax:

```
doMethod1 (arg1, arg2, cb)
   {
      this.doMethod2(arg1, arg2, (result) => {cb (result)});
   }
```

Ensures that the "this" in doMethod1 is the same as the "this" in the anonymous callback function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To preserve the lexical scoping of `this` in TypeScript, you use Arrow Function Expressions.

They are defined in section 4.9.2 of the TypeScript Language Specification.

```
ArrowFormalParameters => { return AssignmentExpression ; }
```

Which in code can look like:

```
() => { alert(this.arg1); }
```